# Creating a function which return lengths

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a function which returns the lengths of different input objects and returns -1 if there is not length.The expected output is below:

```
    my_dict = {'a': 23, 'b': 8}
    len_safe(my_dict)
2
    len_safe(7)
-1
```

I want to use exception handling but am confused as to how to start.

Comment: Why would you want to return some magic number instead of throwing an exception and handling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always capture a `TypeError` and return `-1` if there is no `len()`:

```
def len_safe(obj):
    try:
        return len(obj)
    except TypeError:
        return -1
```

I'm not sure of usability of such function, tho.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [**`hasattr`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr) to check if an object has `__len__` as an attribute, and return `-1` otherwise:

```
def safe_len(o):
     return len(o) if hasattr(o, '__len__') else -1
```

In action:

```
>>> safe_len(7)
-1
>>> safe_len([1,2,3])
3
```